# Xcode automatically opening non-existent file and crashing

Tags: xcode, xcode9

**Please note:** This is a pure Xcode question at heart, the fact that I mention ARKit, SceneKit and DAE files is only incidental. Anyone who knows how to deal with Xcode crashing should be able to answer this, regardless of their level of knowledge of ARKit/SceneKit/DAE files!

---

I'm playing around with ARKit and SceneKit and used Blender to export a 3D model to Collada/DAE format. I then opened my Augmented Reality project in Xcode 9, and dragged-n-dropped the folder containing my DAE file under the `Resources/Models.scnassets` folder in my project. Hence the contents of my project's `Resources/Models.scnassets` folder were now:

```
Resources/
  Models.scnassets/
    dog/
    cat/
    myblenderdaemodel/
      myblenderdaemodel.dae
```

Where `myblenderdaemodel/myblenderdaemodel.dae` is the folder + file I just dragged and dropped into my project.

**I then attempted to open the `myblenderdaemodel.dae` file by clicking it, and Xcode immediately crashed.**

I re-opened Xcode and it automatically opened my project and then automatically tried opening my DAE file (since that was the last file that was opened before the crash), and it crashed again.

So I tried opening a *different project in Xcode*, which I am able to do. But anytime I attempt to open my "unhealthy project" in Xcode it attempts to first open my DAE file and crashes.

1. I open Xcode by opening an `.xcodeproj` file of *another* project
2. I then close that other project and attempt to open my sick/unhealthy project that is crashing
3. It attempts to open/load my DAE file in the DAE editor (since it was the last file opened)
4. It immediately crashes

**Although I am interested in understanding why my DAE file is crashing Xcode, I don't *really* care about this file, I just wanted to play around wth it. I *do* care about my project however!**

So on the terminal I removed the `myblenderdaemodel` folder from its `Resources/Models.scnassets` parent directory, and also used `grep` to confirm there weren't any other references to the phrase `myblenderdaemodel` inside my project folder. I am convinced it has been completely removed, as well as any references to it have been removed...

But I am still unable to open Xcode...the 4 steps above keep happening, **Xcode is convinced there is still a file in my project called `myblenderdaemodel.dae` and it is attempting to open it.**

My theory is that perhaps Xcode stores project information inside its own directory somewhere, and when you load that project, it pulls data from this cache and loads the project with that data, and perhaps that data still contains references to my (now deleted) DAE file.

Either way, **what's the fix here?** How do I open Xcode in such a way

Comment: did you clear the derived data (from trash also), before open?

Comment: Thanks @V12 yes I opened another project, closed it, went to `File >> Workspace Settings`, then opened the **Derived Data** folder, selected the derived data folder for my "sick" project and selected **Move to Trash**. I then tried re-opening my project and the exact same thing happened (its still trying to open that bad DAE file and is crashing).

Comment: Hi do you know the solution for it?

Comment: I am facing the same issue with my XCODE 9.2